# Центрирование блоков внутри блока

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Доброго времени суток. Хочу реализовать следующее (см. схему)
[image: Хочу реализовать]

Внутри блока #wrapper (ширина не фиксирована) есть множество блоков div фиксированной ширины и высоты с float:left. Однако т.к. эти блоки прижаты к левому краю, не получается их центрировать, как на рисунке выше.

Не подскажете, как быть?

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
#wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 0;
}
#wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 140px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

делаете через `display: inline-block` а не `float`, но у данного метода есть ньюанс как отступ у блоков дочерних `#wrapper div`, это решается если поставить `font-size: 0` блоку `#wrapper` в вашем случае, но не забываем обратно возвращать размер шрифта`#wrapper div` чтоб если там будит текст его было видно.

Comment: а что за нюанс? В смысле, в чём именно он проявляется?

Comment: если убрать у родителя display: table(он там в принципе не нужен) и убрать font-size: 0;  то у плиток появится отступ лишний, иногда он вовсе не нужен и даже мешает.

Comment: из за того что плитки становятся display: inline-block; они становятся как бы и блоками так и инлайновыми элементами, а у инлайнов(к примеру у текста) есть так называемый межбуквеный отсуп, который при использовании display: inline-block проявляется в виде такого вот лишнего отступа. Думаю что понятно объяснил)))

Comment: А вообще если не нужно поддержка старых браузеров к примеру ie9 и ниже, то использовать уже нужно flex-box, это будущее всей верстки, про него найдете в гугле))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и комментарии! Поддержка, увы, нужна.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
#wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```